# Random walk on a non-(hyper)cubic lattice

Tags: random-walk

(*In what follows, "cubic lattice" is short for "simple cubic lattice"*)

In [this book](http://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/8842), chapter 12, the following expression is derived for the probability distribution of a random walk on a $D-$dimensional cubic lattice (hypercubic lattice):

$$P_D(\vec x, t) = \left( \frac{D}{2 \pi t}\right)^{D/2} \exp \left(-\frac{D \|\vec x\|^2 }{2 t a^2}\right)$$

where $a$ is the lattice spacing and $\| \cdot\|$ is the euclidean norm.

I am interested in the equivalent expression in the case in which a non-hypercubic lattice is considered; in particular, I am interested in the $D=3$ case.

For example, it would be interesting to consider a [diamond cubic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_cubic) or fcc lattice in $3D$, where the number of nearest neighbors is respectively $4$ and $12$, as opposed to the $6$ nearest neighbors of the cubic lattice.

I tried to work it out myself, but I'm having some trouble. So, the question is: **is there any known (analytical or numerical) result for the three dimensional random walk on non-cubic lattice**?

As I said, I am mostly interested in the $3D$ case, but every information regarding the $D-$dimensional case will be also much appreciated.